# Windows Server 2016 VPN / RAS Connection fails

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2016, windows-10, rras, connection-refused

Sorry for the screenshots being in german.

**Environments:**

- Server: Windows Server 2016
- Client: Windows 10 Pro

**My goal:**

- Running a VPN Service on the Server
- Connecting to it from the client

**What I've done:**

I've added the `DirectAccess and VPN (RAS)` feature.

[image]

Then I've enabled `Routing and RAS`.

[image]

Then I've enabled `Dial in` for the Administrator

[image]

Here is a proof of not having any restrictions to the connections.

[image]

My clients setup and my try to connect.

[image]

> The remote-connection has been declined because of the username and password being invalid or **a not valid selected authentication-protocol for the RAS-server**.

Remote-access eventlog

[image]

> The user Administrator, which established a connection with 87.xxxxxx failed to authenticate: The connection has been refused due to the configured policies on the RAS/VPN-server... username and password invalid or authentication-protocols are not matching with the one configured in the connection-profile.

I can to 100% say that the credentials are correct. I even copied them out of notepad to be sure not having any typos in it. By the way I dont know whats ment with `auth-protocol in the connection-profile`. Which connection-profile?

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Weird error message and also weird solution. I've set an IP-range (IPv4) to the RAS for the clients and the connection imediately worked.

*Special thanks to **ruNN0r** for his solution which I've found [here](https://administrator.de/forum/windows-server-2012-vpn-verbindung-update-nicht-m%C3%B6glich-311566.html).*